# search for a keyword in source code in several hg repos (only tip revision)?

Tags: search, mercurial, grep

I have multiple hg repos

Now I want to find a keyword from all source code of the tip revision in these repos.

It's like `grep keyword hg_dir` but only limit to hg `tip` revision files.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, found a way myself, not perfect, but works.

```
for dir in ./*;
  do
  hg grep keyword .
done;
```

However you can't get all results using `hg grep -r tip`.

You can't use grep's options like `-A` or `-B` as well.